# Fargate service not respecting security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I am unable to connect from a Fargate container to an RDS instance when its ingress is limited through security groups. I can connect with lambdas though.

The container has no issue hitting SQS, or the internet. Only has issues hitting the RDS endpoint.

Here is an excerpt from the template, where the database ingress is open. Fargate can connect without issue.

```
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      PlatformVersion: 1.3.0
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
        MaximumPercent: 200
      DesiredCount: 0
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref DatabaseAccessSecurityGroup

  DatabaseInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      Engine: mysql
      EngineVersion: 8.0.16
      AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt PrivateSubnet1.AvailabilityZone
      PubliclyAccessible: false
      ...
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DatabaseSecurityGroup

  DatabaseSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Cloudformation managed Db subnet group
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  DatabaseSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupName: database-sg
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: Access to RDS
          # allowing all works with Fargate
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 3306
          ToPort: 3306
          IpProtocol: tcp

  DatabaseAccessSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: database-access-sg
      GroupDescription: Security group for accessing db
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

But if I change the `DatabaseSecurityGroup` Group ingress to only allow ingress through `DatabaseAccessSecurityGroup` I get errors when trying to connect through Fargate. Lambdas using the same security group have no issue.

```
   SecurityGroupIngress:
     - Description: Access to RDS
       CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
       SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt DatabaseAccessSecurityGroup.GroupId
       FromPort: 3306
       ToPort: 3306
       IpProtocol: tcp
```

Is there any way to get the Fargate Service to respect security group rules?

Comment: Fargate does "respect" security group rules. The configuration you are describing works for me. Are you sure there is not some other issue here?

Comment: If this is working for your then there must be some other issue here. What could I look for? The container can hit the open internet and SQS. Lambdas using the same security group can hit the db, yet the fargate container cannot.

Comment: Are those Lambdas running in the same VPC in the same subnet(s) that the ECS Fargate task is running?

Comment: I checked those. Same subnet and vpc. But I realized the eni associated with my Fargate task does not have the updated security groups (no database access)! Still looking for a solution, but I think I found the problem.

Comment: Your `DatabaseAccessSecurityGroup` does not have any inbound rules.

Comment: Should you be specifying both CidrIp & SourceSecurityGroupId in the same definition?

Also - can you check in the console how the security group looks once created, maybe something isn't deploying properly via CloudFormation.

Comment: @Marcin what inbound rules do you think that security group needs?

Comment: @AdamLuchjenbroers, I checked the ENIs and they didn't have the sg's deployed to the service via cfn because these tasks were spun up via ecs runTask, not the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was occurring because I was using a `Service` in the `Cloudformation` template, but spinning up the tasks via `ecs.runTask`, which overrode the security groups in the `Service`.